# Reach into the subject of a foreach

Tags: php

When I loop over an array of arrays with `foreach`, I can directly reach into the next dimension using the `list()` keyword (or shorthand `[]` notation) like this:

```
$array_num = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
];

foreach ($array_num as [$deep_value]) {
    echo $deep_value, ' ';
}
// prints: 1 4

$array_assoc = [
    ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2, 'baz' => 3],
    ['foo' => 4, 'bar' => 5, 'baz' => 6],
];

foreach ($array_assoc as ['baz' => $deep_value]) {
    echo $deep_value, ' ';
}
// prints: 3 6
```

Is there a similar concept for arrays of objects?

```
class Example {
    public $foo;
    public function __construct(int $number = 1) {
        $this->foo = $number;
    }
}

$array_obj = [
    new Example,
    new Example(4),
];
foreach ($array_obj as foo<-$object) { // obviously wrong
    echo $object, ' ';
}
```

---

The use case is exactly the same as with the initial feature (unpacking nested arrays into variables). One example would be accessing a large number of properties in an object:

```
foreach ($array_assoc as ['foo' => $foo, 'bar' => $bar, 'baz' => $baz]) {
    $speed = $baz / $foo / $bar;
    echo "The $foo horses ate $baz apples in the last $bar hours.\n";
    echo "That's $speed apples per horse per hour!\n\n";
}
```

which scales in the order of (2) x (sum of property name lengths).

vs.

```
foreach ($array_obj as $object) {
    $speed = $object->baz / $object->foo / $object->bar;
    echo "The {$object->$foo} horses ate {$object->$baz} apples in the last {$object->$bar} hours.\n";
    echo "That's $speed apples per horse per hour!\n\n";
}
```

which scales in the order of (length of object variable name) x (number of uses within the loop).

or

```
foreach ($array_obj as $object) {
    [$foo, $bar, $baz] = [$object->foo, $object->bar, $object->baz];
    $speed = $baz / $foo / $bar;
    echo "The $foo horses ate $baz apples in the last $bar hours.\n";
    echo "That's $speed apples per horse per hour!\n\n";
}
```

which scales in the order of (length of object variable name) x (sum of property name lengths).

With small loops or few properties, this makes little difference. With increasing lengths of variable names and uses within the loops, the last two methods quickly become significantly more verbose and harder to read. Bottom line, I either

- give my object an irresponsibly short name,
- spam my loop with `$object->`, or
- retrieve all the object properties at the start of the loop in a rather verbose fashion, which makes the assignment of the object variable obsolete in the first line of the loop.

Neither is particularly conducive to readable and maintainable code. Defining right in the loop which properties I want, as it can be done with arrays, would allow me to use reasonable variable names, skip object references throughout my loop, and assign only as many variables as I actually need. Basically, it turns `foreach` statements into equivalents to function statements that get called multiple times and retain the current scope.

Comment: I am not sure what output you are expecting, and why changing `echo $object, ' ';` into `echo $object->foo, ' ';` is not enough. Do you want to get the "first property" of objects from different classes?

Comment: This is a simplified example, the use case is exactly the same as with the array/list version. For example, if I'm extracting a bunch of properties and need them in their own variables so I can modify them or use them often without referencing the object every time, writing 10 lines of `$varX = $object->propertyX` is quite cumbersome and verbose. I'd like to be able to just unpack them the same way I could by transforming the object into an array first.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that an important piece of the puzzle is missing, but as the question stands right now, I don't see a reason why this snippet would not do what you expect:

```
class Example {
    public $foo;
    public function __construct(int $number = 1) {
        $this->foo = $number;
    }
}

$array = [
    new Example,
    new Example(4),
];
foreach ($array as $object) {
    echo $object->foo, ' ';
}
// prints: 1 4
```

Comment: The question is not about behaviour, this snippet does what I expect, just as `echo $subarray[0]` or `echo $subarray['baz']` would do the same thing in my first 2 examples. The difference between the 2 respective versions isn't what they do, it's how verbose they are, which affects how well/quickly they can be written, read, understood and maintained. Imagine this example with not just one echo for one property, but 20 operations on 7 properties. Adding an extra `object->` every time quickly inflates the code. I've added a detailed use case description to the question.